# Imagem se repetindo

Tags: jquery

Implementei um código em meu site, este é um chatbox retrátil. Ele tem duas imagens, uma destas é para abrir o chatbox e outra para fechar.
Porem, quando se abre o chatbox, ele fica com duas imagens de "Closed" como pode ver abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que apenas ficasse a imagem ao lado.

Código:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    s="jQuery('#chatboxpop').animate({width:'toggle'},350); jQuery('#chatboxopen,#chatboxclose').toggle();";
    jQuery('body').prepend('<div style="overflow: visible; position: fixed; bottom: 30px; height: 400px; right: 0px; z-index:1000;"><iframe src="http://bloodypalacerpg.chatango.com/" id="chatboxpop" scrolling="yes" style="height: 300px; border: 2px solid #000000; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; float: right; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; display: none; width:600px" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe><div onclick="'+s+'" style="margin-top: 10px; cursor :pointer; float:left"><img src="http://i34.servimg.com/u/f34/16/04/51/75/open10.png" id="chatboxopen" style="display: inline; "><img src="http://i34.servimg.com/u/f34/16/04/51/75/close10.png" id="chatboxclose" style="cursor: pointer; display: none; "></div></div>')

});
```

Comment: Verifica se há somente um `<body>`.

Comment: Pelo visto está sendo criado duas imagem de close uma quando o chat está fechado e outra ao abrir, o que poderia ver é inspecionar o html com o f12 e verificar se isso está ocorrendo, se estiver você terá que tratar para o abrir o chat dar um .hide() na imagem que está na tela.

Comment: Sim, há apenas um.

Comment: Rodrigo, eu já verifiquei no inspecionar elemento, apenas há um código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de usar `.prepend()` ou `.append()` tente usar `.html()` esta irá substituir os elementos.

Por exemplo:  `$('#' + div).html(valor);`

Outro exemplo:

```
$('#' + div).html(<span style="opacity:0;">Valor</span>);
$('#' + div span).animate({opacity:1},slow);
```

Comment: Certo! Funcionou. ^^

Comment: Precisar de algo, pode chamar! Bem vindo ao stackoverflow.

Comment: Obrigado. :D ^^